# Multiplying $_POST

Tags: php, post, int

I am trying to make a simple program where the user can multiply their inputs. But it always return a 0.

I already did:

```
$price = (int)$_POST['txtPrice'];

$quan = (int)$_POST['quantity'];


$ans = $quan * $price;
echo "$ans";
```

But returns 0 always.
This is the page where all the textboxes came from:

```
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td><input type='text' name='quantity' placeholder='How Many?'></td>";
echo "<td><input type='text' name='txtName' value='$name'></td>";
echo "<td><input type='text' name='txtPrice' value='$price'></td>";
```

Comment: Your form is `method="post"`???  Basic debugging `print_r($_POST);`

Comment: What values are you seeing submitted?

Comment: Why are there quotes around $ans?  Another issue would be that your price should not be an INT.  It should be a decimal.

Comment: `var_dump($_POST)`, and see if you actually got what you are simply ASSUMING you got.

Comment: @durbnpoisn: cargo-cult programming, that's why.

Comment: There is a typo in your code, a missing `'` in the `txtName` input.

Answer (score 0):

Using your same code and just adding the form tag and a submit works for me:

```
<?php

if(!empty($_POST)) {
    print_r($_POST);
    $price = (int)$_POST['txtPrice'];
    $quan = (int)$_POST['quantity'];

    $ans = $quan * $price;
    echo "$ans<br>";
}

echo "<tr>";
echo "<form action='index.php' method='post'>";
echo "<td><input type='text' name='quantity' placeholder='How Many?'>    </td>";
echo "<td><input type='text' name='txtName' value='$name'></td>";
echo "<td><input type='text' name='txtPrice' value='$price'></td>";
echo "<input type='submit'>";
echo "</form>";
```

Execute it with php -S 127.0.0.1 index.php, $ans contains the value from the multiplication.